# page loads a text/csv file when put in user ID

Tags: php

hi, I've got a problem MAYBE regarding cookies..

I have an affiliate site, where users put in their ID at the url and it will redirect to their own sites...

www.mydomain.com/userID ...

I was doing the development in `XAMPP` ..and now i need to put it in the server, which is using windows server 2008, and using `WAMP` ...
the problem is, when user puts in their ID in the url, the browser prompts a download page.

example, when user puts in 'Bejoi' in the url (www.mydomain.com/bejoi)..it prompts a download box to download 'Bejoi' file.. it recognise the files as text/csv ..

but any other links, doesn't prompt that download box..all other php links are working fine..

it was ok in my localhost, and my LINUX testing server. anybody can help with this? i would very much appreciate it...

Comment: paste code and look at the headers you are applying in pages

Comment: which code? the php function code?

Comment: u can check the site here
www.excelwithus.com.my/estore2

if u enter 'bejoi' ..without the ' ' ..it will create a cookie for bejoi and redirect to bejoi's site..

but at the server site, http://110.4.43.13/estore2 .. inserting the bejoi ID..will prompt a download box ..

is this a server related issue or coding issue?

Comment: how ur setting your cookies??

Comment: what seeting? in the server?
have u seen the link i gave?